# Extracting holes from polygons in shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon-creation, extract, holes

Is there a way to select the holes (gaps) in a vector shapefile in QGIS, like the "Fill holes" function which recognizes them indirectly?

I need to get the holes from the original shapefile and work with them. Is there a way in other software like Arc?

Comment: by definition you can't select a hole as it is not part of a polygon. You could try generating a big polygon and subtracting your polygons,

Comment: You can digitize them manually, you can convert polygons to lines, then select the lines around the holes and convert them to polygons, or you can use difference on a mask layer.

Comment: @IanTurton a hole is usually defined as an inner ring of a Polygon, making it perfectly selectable...

Comment: @geozelot - you can select the boundary of the hole but not the hole itself

Comment: @IanTurton okay, well, so you can equally only ever select the boundary of a Polygon, but not the Polygon itself? What about the actual Linestrings of the boundary, they are only vectors, described by two (0 dimensional) points? ;-D Guess we can argue all day, point is, if you want these holes to be Polygons, select the inner rings. It's trivial.

Comment: @geozelot - qgis is perfectly capable of selecting a polygon by clicking any where in it, if you click in the hole it will not be selected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't mind a two step process:

1. Run ["Delete Holes"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#delete-holes) from QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) on your "PolygonWithHoles"
2. Run ["Difference"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference) and use your "Cleaned" *(Result from Delete Holes)* as Input and your "PolygonWithHoles" as Overlay:

   [image]

*Result:*

[image]

Comment: This works alright :)

Answer (score 8):

If you wish a one-step solution, you could also use ["Geometry by Expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) with this expression:

```
difference(
    make_polygon(exterior_ring($geometry)),
    $geometry
    )
```

or a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`with this query:

```sql
select difference(make_polygon(exterior_ring(geometry)),geometry)
from PolygonWithHoles
```

Both will return a *MultiPolygon* of the holes.